# Hollowing out an object evenly?

Tags: modeling

How do I take a mesh(currently working on the upper receiver of a gun) and hollow out the inside so that all the internal faces are lined up with their respective exterior face evenly throughout the entire mesh?

Comment: Please add screenshots to your question so we can help you and give you a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might achieve the desired effect by using a solidify modifier or by extruding the faces and scale them along their normals using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>.

Comment: The normals is the way the face is pointed correct?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: The solidify modifier in certain situations will alter the surface for instance a cone tip will cave in on itself. What's needed is a shape that is generated as a negative distance from the normals of the surface that is booleaned from the interior of the geometry.

Comment: I don't know why you didn't get upvotes on this but I just wanted to add a comment that this was exactly what I personally needed and thanks for the answer, it helped me a bunch

Answer (score 1):

I think for me in certain situations you have to duplicate the object, extrude faces along their normals negatively, invert that selection so to delete the original ones and then manually cut off the faces for parts that have gone inverted. Then close those openings by making faces from the edge loops or better merge those openings vertices at center.

Then you boolean that from the original.

For my example thinner parts like a cone shape would self collide maybe akin to beveling edges past themselves when trying the solidify route.

One problem is then you still have to make sure those points are not thinner then you need for 3D printing for instance.

Another example might be an antenna. If you solidify you'll have this kind of problem and if you leave the antenna it could be too thin or fragile for printing anyway.

A final thought is just to sculpt out from a sphere shape the areas you want hollow maybe something like carving out a pumpkin, but in reverse. Although you could boolean a sphere out and then try sculpting from the inside with the near clipping plan set appropriately close (and a short/wide camera lens).

Also I think some 3D printing software will do it properly for (with supports if needed etc.) so you might not need to do anything in blender initially despite the instinct to do that initially.

It would look more natural like as if a glass blower made it as well, if you do it the way I originally suggested and not as procedural as one would expect to be able to.

Oh please remember you also might have to leave a significant hole for powder or support removal, or pressure issues in kiln firing or just environment changes.

[image: It's suppose to be a hummingbird.]

Answer (score 1):

Doing this properly in Blender is impossible, but you can do it very easily in Meshmixer.  I export an .stl from Blender which I then load in to Meshmixer.  Then use Meshmixer's hollow tool which gives you fantastic control and will generate a perfectly hollowed object with no broken geometry.  It works incredible fast too.